# How kernel treats two user level threads?

Tags: multithreading, kernel, multicore

After reading many threads related material, I'm still confused about the ULT and KLT.
How kernel treats two ULT of same process? Can two user level threads of same process run simultaneously on multi core CPU? If yes, is it done by kernel or library function?

Comment: Which kernel ? Different operating systems might do this differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the Linux version 2.6, the standard implementation is [NPTL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_POSIX_Thread_Library) 
(Native Posix Thread Library) which assign **1 User level thread** to **1 kernel thread** (actually Linux "knows" only **tasks** -not processes neither threads- circa 8kb of kernel memory).

Just in case of a multi-processor/core machine (**CONFIG_SMP** defined in the kernel code) one thread may be allocated on any available processor. In Linux any processor has a "run-queue" (which in case of **SCHED_NORMAL** or **SCHED_OTHER** a red-black tree data structure is used to contain a list of task ready to run. "Migration" of task between two run-queue is possible.

I hope this help to clarify!

_ _

Kasper.

Answer (score 0):

> Can two user level threads of same process run simultaneously on multi core CPU?

Yes, one of the main reasons to use threads is to increase performance by working concurrently on independent computations.

> If yes, is it done by kernel or library function?

The kernel is responsible for managing the resources provided by the hardware, including the multiple cores in a multi core CPU.  The kernel provides a programming interface (system calls) to be used by user space libraries, which in turn provide an interface (abstraction layer) to user applications.  There are many libraries and programming language extensions for managing threads, here's a good overview

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/choosing-the-right-threading-framework

In short, the kernel ultimately is where threads are created, scheduled to run, context switched, wait for events, and destroyed.  Multi-threaded user programs use library functions and/or language extensions to manage threads, these provide different abstraction levels above the kernel.